# How to implement Command with Tooltip in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tooltip, icommand

Most MVVM frameworks implement basic Command pattern (for example DelegateCommand in PRISM), that uses Execute and CanExecute methods from ViewModel.

Hovewer, I often need to add a tooltip to the command. For example, I want to describe the purpose of a command or explain, why it has been disabled.

Currently my tooltips are independent, but this results in code duplication of style definitions.

**Is there a way to integrate tooltips with the MVVM Command pattern?**
Should I create my own Command class, or is it considered bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just extend PRISM's ['Delegate Command'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx) and add a `ToolTip` property?

```
public class DelegateCommandEx : DelegateCommand 
{
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

I believe by default WPF commands don't have that property because a `ToolTip` doesn't have to be a string in WPF - it can be an object, a control, a group of controls, etc

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is perfectly valid. I'm not aware of such a command. `RoutedUICommand` is the closest I can think of, but it's obviously routed (no good for MVVM) and only defines a `Text` property - no `ToolTip`.

As you've hinted, you could certainly define your own. Alternatively, you could define some kind of command registration service, whereby modules register `ICommand` implementations along with metadata about that command (including the tooltip).

Answer (score 0):

An [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) is a way to bind to events raised by the UI in MVVM. It doesn't have a `ToolTip` property, and I don't see how this is useful as the command is acting as a handler and has no UI. Are you referring to a ToolTip specific Command in which case it does make sense?

Generally you would use the [ToolTipService](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/wpf-sample-series-data-binding-in-tooltip/) with WPF.

Comment: ToolTipService doesn't help me, it's too complicated. What I mean is that my typical button has a hint tooltip (simple text), you may say it's the Command's documentation, so it may be part of the command.

Comment: In which framework? [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616875.aspx)